# Use contour integration to compute the Fourier transform,

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, singularity-theory

The problem statement is:

Use contour integration to determine the Fourier transform,
$\large \hat f(ξ)=∫_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{−iξx}dx$,

of $\large f(x)=\frac{1}{2−2x−x^2}$.

Some issues that I am running into are:

**Attempt #1**

I originally chose a lower semi-circular contour, since the negative i on the exponential function will help give the needed estimate of zero along the semi-circular contour, as we let it grow to infinity - on the upper semi-circular contour, the positive imaginary axis poses problems for the factor $e^{-i\xi x}$.

But then the two simple poles of the function are lying on the real axis.

So I had thought of perhaps, when integrating along the real axis, perhaps jump over the two poles, and estimate the integrand on those two tiny circles and show it goes to zero.

But then, my contour would enclose...no poles...and my function would be analytic on *and inside* the closed contour, and by Cauchy's theorem, my integration yields **zero**.

**Attempt #2**

Now, in hopes of *enclosing* the two (or at least one?) poles, I chose a box contour instead.  A box of height 8, so 4 units above and below the real axis.  This is a square box to start, and ensures that both poles are enclosed.  I then parameterized fixing the width of the box and hoping to let the length of the box grow to infinity.  Then perhaps, integration along the top and bottom edges of this box, which will be integration with respect to the **x** variable, will give me two desired integrals.  Unfortunately, it looks like these desirable integrals are canceling each other out (of course, by the parametrization of the box).

Now I'm not sure what to do.

Any hints or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: Your function is neither $L^1$ nor $L^2$, it has non-integrable singularities in $x=-1\pm\sqrt 3$. In what sence do you consider your Fourier tranform? Distributions?

Comment: Hi @TZakrevskiy, I am primarily looking to compute the integral and do not have much expertise with the topic of Fourier transforms.  This is an old qualifying exam question in complex analysis, dating back to 1995.  When you say "it has non-integrable singularities", are you saying that computation by the method of residues is not even applicable?  Thanks,

Comment: "Non-integrable singularities" means $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) e^{-ix\xi}\,dx$ doesn't exist as a Lebesgue integral, nor as an improper Riemann integral. So the Fourier transform in the classical integral sense doesn't exist. However, the Fourier transform exists in some wider sense, e.g. interpreting $f$ as a tempered distribution. Cut things short, you need the Cauchy principal value of the integral, Attempt 1 works well for that, and the point is that the integral over the small (semi-)circles doesn't yield $0$, the limit will be your result.

Comment: there are no poles on real line

Comment: Thanks as always, for your awesome responses, @DanielFischer -- I will continue to proceed with the first attempt now :-)

Comment: One further remark. Whether you need to close the contour in the upper or in the lower half-plane depends on the sign of $\xi$.

Comment: Ok, I will distinguish two cases, @DanielFischer.  Thanks,

Comment: Hi @DanielFischer, if I consider case 1, with $\xi$ >0, on the small semi-circles of radius = $\epsilon$, the integrals limit to $\frac {1}{2} \pi \epsilon$, integrand limit value multiplied by the arc length of $\pi \epsilon$.  If I then sum the contributions from both semi-circles, I get a total value of $\pi \epsilon$.  What do you think?  And, I'm not sure what to do with the integration on the rest of the real line. (The estimate on the semicircle was easy to show.)   Thanks,

Comment: Also, checking with Wolfram Alpha, it tells me that the integral does not converge, @DanielFischer.  Thanks,

Comment: Right, the integral doesn't converge, the poles are non-integrable singularities. You need to interpret the integral as a principal value integral. Wolfram Alpha may or may not understand if you tell it to treat it "as a principal value integral".

Comment: Actually, in computing a second time around the small semi-circles, I realize the numerators of the integrands goes to $\large e^{i \xi (-1 +/-  \sqrt{3})}$, as the radius goes to zero, I think, @DanielFischer.  What do you think?  Also, still don't know what to do with the integration on the real line away from the two poles...thanks,

Comment: Ohh...zero contribution from integrating over the rest of the real line, I think -- just from Cauchy-Goursat's theorem, @DanielFisher.  The integrand is analytic on the closed contour that is free of singularities.

Comment: So, my final answer is $(\large  \frac {e^{-i \xi (-1-\sqrt{3})}}{2} + \frac{e^{-i\xi (-1+\sqrt{3})}}{2}) \pi \epsilon$, @DanielFischer.  Please feel free to comment further.  I will move on to other problems now and revisit this one later.  Thanks for your time,

Comment: What is $\epsilon$? What you ought to get is $\pm \pi i$ times the sum of the residues. That looks similar, but is not the same.

Comment: Hi @DanielFischer, $\epsilon$ is the radius of the two small semi-circles.  Basically, integrand constant times arc length, in the limit.  I didn't compute any residues, since I didn't think the residue theorem is applicable?  The contour doesn't enclose the poles, does it?  Then the winding number of the contour at both poles is zero.  Unless you are combining the large upper and lower semi-circular contours?  Thanks,

Comment: At the poles, the integrand is $\frac{a}{z - z_0}$ plus negligible stuff. You let the radius tend to $0$, then the integral over the negligible stuff tends to $0$, and the integral over the principal part to $\pm \pi i a$ (the sign depends on the orientation of the semicircle).

Comment: Hi @DanielFischer -- are you using something called a "dog-bone" contour?  I am just reading up a bit on this contour now - perhaps I should use it?  The dog-bone part of the contour would enclose the two poles and then allow me to compute residues, I think.  I just found a link on an older MSE question...thanks,

Comment: No dogbone, just two small semicircular indents at the poles.

Comment: Ok, got it.  I will continue with this after some sleep.  Thanks so much for your time and help @DanielFischer.  Have a great night :-)

Comment: Hi @DanielFischer, I got the correct answer that matches the answer below by Ron Gordon - but my work was for the case where $\xi$ is positive.  I will now show the work for the other case.  It's entirely possible that the answer can be piecewise-defined and have a dependence on the sign of $\xi$, right?  So, that I must show the work for both cases.  Also, in the integrals over the small semi-circles, I had to swap $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}$  with the integral sign.

Comment: Is this just an application of dominated convergence theorem, viewing the integrand as a sequence of functions, with quantifier $\epsilon$ instead of the usual quantifier $n$, where $n$ goes to infinity.  Same story, right?  (The integrand is clearly bounded by an integrable function, over the integration interval.)  Thanks @DanielFischer

Comment: It depends on how you do it. If you parametrise the semicircle over the interval $[0,\pi]$ (or $[-\pi,0]$, …) you get an integrand that depends on $\varepsilon$, and then you can apply the DCT (but you need only something much weaker, since the convergence is uniform). Generally, you can apply the DCT to families depending on a real parameter $t$ because sequences are sufficient to describe the topology of $\mathbb{R}$. If the whole family doesn't converge, there's a sequence in the family that doesn't converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for $\xi \lt 0$ the contour integral

$$\oint_C dz \frac{e^{-i \xi z}}{2-2 z-z^2} $$

where $C$ is a semicircle of radius $R$ in the upper half plane, with a small semicircular indent into the upper half-plane of radius $\epsilon$ at each pole $z_{\pm}=-1 \pm \sqrt{3}$.  The contour integral is then

$$PV \int_{-R}^R dx \frac{e^{-i \xi x}}{2-2 x-x^2} +i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{e^{-i \xi (z_-+\epsilon e^{i \phi})}}{3-(-\sqrt{3}+\epsilon e^{i \phi})^2}\\ + i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{e^{-i \xi (z_++\epsilon e^{i \phi})}}{3-(\sqrt{3}+\epsilon e^{i \phi})^2}+ i R \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{e^{-i \xi R e^{i \theta}}}{2-2 R e^{i \theta} - R^2 e^{i 2 \theta}}$$

In the limit as $R \to \infty$, the fourth integral vanishes as $1/R^2$.  As $\epsilon \to 0$, the sum of the second and third integrals converge to

$$i \frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{3}} \left (-e^{-i \xi z_-} + e^{-i \xi z_+} \right ) $$

By Cauchy's theorem, the contour integral is equal to zero.  Thus, for $\xi \lt 0$ we have

$$PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-i \xi x}}{2-2 x-x^2} = -\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}} e^{i \xi} \sin{\left (\sqrt{3} \xi \right )} $$

For $\xi \gt 0$, one uses a contour in the lower half plane.

Comment: Hi @RonGordon, what happens when your first integral passes the two poles -- isn't there a blow-up?  And for the second and third integrals, how do you get the $pi / 2\sqrt{3}$?  Aren't the denominators 3-3=0?  Thanks,

Comment: @user283090: No, the contour is designed to avoid the poles.  The second and third integrals are the detours around the poles, and they each pick up a nonzero contribution.  I urge you to work out the algebra yourself.

Comment: Ok, will do so now.   Thanks so much for your answer, @RonGordon.

Comment: Can I ask you a silly follow-up question @RonGordon:  shouldn't your upper integration limits for the second and third integrals be 2pi?  Or it shouldn't matter?  Thanks,

Comment: No.  The semicircle is traversed above the real line clockwise from the left to the right. The left is at $\pi$ and the right is at $0$.  When you go below the contour, you are still going clockwise but below the real line.  In that case, you are going from $2 \pi$ to $\pi$.  In the end, it doesn't really matter, just that you are going clockwise.

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much @RonGordon :-)

Comment: Hi @RonGordon - I'm writing out the second integral in full detail (and will do so for the third integral shortly) and looking good so far and I match your answer, but off by a minus sign.  I have $\large \frac {i \pi}{2 \sqrt{3}}e^{-i \xi (-1-\sqrt{3})}$.  Are you sure your minus sign is correct?  And also, in evaluating the limit, as epsilon goes down to zero from the right, is it just a standard Dominated Convergence Theorem application?

Comment: The integrand, after simplifying it a ton, looked clearly bounded by an integrable function over the integration interval.  Then taking the limit inside the integral sign just reduces the integrand to a constant.  Am I on the right track?  Thanks, @RonGordon,

Comment: Dominated Convergence Theorem, whenever the integrand is bounded by an integrable function, allows the switching of *any* limit with the integral sign, right? I'm confident about the switching of limits at infinity, letting n go to infinity for a sequence of functions $f_n$ inside the integral sign, but I'm not so sure that swapping limits at zero with the integral sign -- such as in this problem - is also an application of Dominated Convergence Theorem.  Thanks,

Comment: Sorry, I should also mention that the answer I gave you, for the first pole, is for $\xi$ >0.  Perhaps that is why we are off by a minus sign...thanks @RonGordon.  I'll proceed with the third integral (and then do it all over again for $\xi$ <0) ...

Comment: Hi @RonGordon - I spoke too soon.  My final answer, combining the second and third integrals, and then moving both terms over to the R.H.S. (since by Cauchy's theorem, the sum of all the integrals were zero because of analyticity of the integrand on and inside the contour), is exactly the same as yours.  Is there actually a need to show all of this work now for $\xi$ <0?  Or, can I just state that the contour would just be chosen with an upper semi-circle instead.

Comment: Actually, I think it's definitely possible that the answer can be piecewise-defined for $\xi$ positive or negative, so I really should break it out into two cases.  It's not that much more work to show it.  And for this specific problem, we already know that the answer is not piecewise-defined, since you presented your answer for $\xi$ <0, and I have the same answer for $\xi$>0.  Unless you think this sort of problem would *never*, ever be piecewise-defined and never have a dependence on the *sign* of the inputs, then please let me know.  Thanks so much @RonGordon.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

\begin{align}
\hat{\on{f}}\pars{\xi} & \equiv
\bbox[5px,#ffd]{%
\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{−\ic\xi x} \over
2 - 2x - x^{2}}\,\dd x} =
-\expo{\ic\xi}\,\mrm{P.V.}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{−\ic\xi x} \over x^{2} - 3}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-{\root{3} \over 6}\expo{\ic\xi}\,\mrm{P.V.}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{−\ic\xi x}\pars{%
{1 \over x - \root{3}} - {1 \over x + \root{3}}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-{\root{3} \over 6}\expo{\ic\xi}\,\sum_{\sigma = \pm}
\sigma\,\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\expo{−\ic\xi x} \over x - \sigma\root{3}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-{\root{3} \over 6}\expo{\ic\xi}\,\sum_{\sigma = \pm}
\sigma\left[%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\expo{−\ic\xi x} \over x - \sigma\root{3} + \ic 0^{+}}\,\dd x
\right.
\\[2mm] &\ \phantom{-{\root{3} \over 6}\expo{\ic\xi}\,\sum_{\sigma = \pm}
\sigma\left[\right.}
+ \left.\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\expo{−\ic\xi x}\,\ic\pi\,\delta\pars{x - \sigma\root{3}}\,\dd x
\right]
\\[5mm] = &\
-{\root{3} \over 6}\expo{\ic\xi}\,\sum_{\sigma = \pm}
\sigma\bracks{%
-\bracks{\xi < 0}2\pi\ic\expo{−\ic\xi\pars{\sigma\root{3}}} +
\ic\pi\expo{−\ic\xi\sigma\root{3}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-{\root{3} \over 6}\expo{\ic\xi}\,\pi\ic\
\overbrace{\braces{-2\bracks{\xi < 0} + 1}}
^{\ds{\on{sgn}\pars{\xi}}}\ 
\overbrace{%
\sum_{\sigma = \pm}\sigma\expo{−\ic\xi\pars{\sigma\root{3}}}}
^{\ds{-2\ic\sin\pars{\root{3}\xi}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{-{\root{3} \over 3}
\,\pi\expo{\ic\xi}\sin\pars{\root{3}\verts{\xi}}} \\ &
\end{align}